# Rails .map produces unwanted ["\n"]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got the following lines in my view:

```
  <p><%= @runnings_past.map do |f| %>
      <%= f.title %>
  <% end %>
  </p>
```

which works just fine in the console --> output:

```
2.1.2 :076 > @runnings_past.map do |f|
2.1.2 :077 >     f.title
2.1.2 :078?>   end
 => ["Murtenlauf"] 
2.1.2 :079 >
```

But when I use it in the view as seen above, I get an expression like this:

```
Murtenlauf ["\n"]
```

Where does the ["\n"] come from?

Comment: not quite understood, that is this `Murtenlauf ["\n"] `?

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= @runnings_past.map do |f| %>
   <%= f.title %>
<% end %>
```

Should actually be

```
<% @runnings_past.each do |f| %>
   <%= f.title %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the lack of `=` (in addition, I changed `map` to `each` because you're just iterating through the array)

`<%=` means evaluate the code and insert the result into the html structure.  So what you were doing was evaluating the `.map` and putting the result into your html.  So you would iterate through the `@runnings_past` code, place the `f.first` into the html (which is what you want) but then when you were done with that, you were placing the result of the mapping (which apparently was an array with a string return character) into the html afterwards.

Comment: I need to use map since otherwise i'm just printing the activerecord:relation but the lack of the '=' did the trick! thanks a lot!!

Comment: You actually don't need the `map` and there will be a performance hit by using it.  [`.map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map) will iterate through the array and whatever the returns from the block will be placed in the current index of that array.  `each` however simply iterates over the array.  Unless there is something else you are doing @runnings_past afterwards where you want it to be an array of return characters, you should really be using `each`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong iterator. You want to use [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-each) instead of [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map). Map creates a new array where each element is the result of each iteration in the block. While [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-each) simply calls the given block once for each element in the array.

In addition, as pointed out by @JTG, you want to remove the `=`. You only need `=` for showing output. You don't need it for logic.